# Android app like Rock Band

Tags: android, music

I'm looking for an Android app similar to the video game Rock Band for XBOX and other gaming platforms. That is, an app where you can do piano, drums, and especially vocals, and get scored. Are there any such apps? Essentially any price is fine.

I know there used to be a Rock Band mobile app, but it seems to have been discontinued.

Comment: There was "Band Multitrack" which was recently unlisted. But there still is [Walk Band Multitrack](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gamestar.pianoperfect) (and maybe [more](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_audioedit#group_863)). Would that fit?

Comment: @Izzy - Those seem to be music production tools, not karaoke style video games.

Comment: Welcome aboard :-) Are you willing to pay for it? If so, please state a budget, otherwise, use the [tag:gratis] tag. Help us to help you :-)

Comment: @Mawg -  I don't really care about cost.

Comment: Thanks. Bets edit your question to say that, as not everyone will read these comments. As a general rule, the more info you can give us, the better we can help you.

Comment: @Obie2.0 maybe your question text then should say you're after "karaoke style video games"? Wasn't clear to me, sorry.